# Entry point of symfony 2 project, redirection

Tags: php, symfony

I just created a symfony 2 project and I use the virtual Host to acces my project with the url my_project.dev.
When I enter this URL it works but it gives me the index of my project. I want to redirect this to a home page but I can't find the route to modify this.

Any help is welcome :)

Comment: Could you please provide the code snippet that illustrate the problem? Thanks!

Comment: sounds like youve not set the document route for the vhost properly.  needs to be something like `...../web` a detailed [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi)

Comment: You need to follow some tutorials about setting up a project. Also look at such topics as enabling .htaccess and mod_rewrite (as you are likely to be using Apache).

Answer (score 1):

I would say you configured the virtual host wrong.

Two things specific for symfony could be wrong here:

1. you didn't point the DocumentRoot to your [pathToProject]/web directory
2. if you did point it here, check how you have DirectoryIndex configured. For symfony it should be app.php or app_dev.php.

The second point is usually handled by .htaccess file, but check if it present in you [pathToProject]/web directory

More resources on how to setup webserver / virtual host for symfony can be found in documentation here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Thx for the answer, i checked the first point about the DocumentRoot and i changed it but I still got the index of my website when accessing my_project.dev

And can you please tell me where I can find the DirectoryIndex, i looked for it in my project but can't find it.

Comment: @ElAndy DocumentIndex is configuration for apache, that says what file to serve by default. It could be defined inside your vhost config or in every .htaccess file .. symfony by default got defined inside the .htacces file that you should check. You should really read the supplied link, as you didn't supply enough information for pin pointing the problem.